# Looking to display random percentages in a cell

Tags: random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to find a way in Google Spreadsheets to show a random percentage between 93% and 96%. This would include, 93%, 94%, etc up to 96% obviously.

I want this in a cell. I currently have:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0.93,0.96)
```

I have also "format as a percentage" for that cell.

What it's displaying is 100%. Why 100%? I don't understand. Can somebody help me understand what I am doing wrong?

I have tried `=RANDBETWEEN` code but it may be wrong.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0.93,0.96)
```

Comment: Change your formula to this: `=RANDBETWEEN(93;96)/100`

Answer (score 2):

`RANDBETWEEN` uses whole values as parameters. Divide by 100 to get the number you are looking for

`=RANDBETWEEN(93, 96)/100`

Answer (score 2):

without formatting it internally it would be:

```
=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(93, 96)/100, "#%")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

`RANDBETWEEN(x,y)` only works with integer values, so it's automatically returning a 1 instead of the decimal value you're trying to use.

To work around this and still use the Percentage formatting in your cell, you can use

`=RANDBETWEEN(93,96)/100`

This should produce the result you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507?hl=en

"Values with decimal parts may be used for low and/or high; this will cause the least and greatest possible values to be the next integer greater than low and/or the next integer less than high, respectively."

RANDBETWEEN will only return integers. Therefore you need to do some math to get the precision you are looking for.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(93, 96)/100
```